# Can I as a customer of Salesforce choose my preferred partner or reseller to purchase licenses?

Tags: licenses, partner, restriction, multi-regional, purchasing

Is anybody aware of a restriction that Salesforce put on my to purchase my licenses. So, if my company is based in Europe can Salesforce forbid me to purchase my licenses via a SF partner or reseller in another region in the world? For example a reseller in the US or in Asia?
I was told by Salesforce, that I can only purchase in my region, but this seems a bit weird and a bit discriminating?
Is there anybody, who has experience with that?

Comment: It is Salesforce policy to sell licences directly to customers, not via third parties. This makes life simpler in many ways, think for example what would happen if the third party stopped paying the licence costs, for some reason. Also, even if a third party bought the licenses on behalf of you, they would probably charge a fee for that. Why would you want to do this?